# Using Nativescript Filterable ListPIcker plugin with Vue.js in NS 7 app

Tags: javascript, android, ios, vue.js, nativescript

I am looking to use the following plugin within my Nativescript 7/ Vue.js app:
https://github.com/nstudio/nativescript-plugins/tree/master/packages/nativescript-filterable-listpicker

Can anyone advise on how I can register the component in my app, and what imports are required.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Have found the solution. I don't understand how I can do exactly the same thing over and over, and all of a sudden it will work out of the blue....

Just use this:

```
import FilterableListpicker from "@nstudio/nativescript-filterable-listpicker";
Vue.registerElement("FilterableListpicker", () => require("@nstudio/nativescript-filterable-listpicker").FilterableListpicker);
```

Remember to also add FilterableListPicker in the components option.

Good luck!

Original answer:
Would love to know the answer to this as I've been trying to fix the error for 2 full days.
I've tried the nstudio (as per the blog post, and above...) and the davecoffin plugin without success.

The davecoffin version gives

```
Error in render: "TypeError: Class constructor FilterableListpicker cannot be invoked without 'new'"
```

whereas the nstudio version gives

```
Error in v-on handler (Promise/async): "TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.. still getting the "cannot be invoked without new" error with the @nstudio version unfortunately.

Comment: Have you fully deleted the davecoffin version, installed the nstudio version, and run ns clean?